# Navigation active class not working on server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I developed a navigation bar. I just add an active class for links that highlight the current link. The strange thing is that the feature is working on my local pc perfectly. I just uploaded it to my server and check, but it's not working at all.

This is the [uploaded site](http://addstudio.lk/Project/drivinginstructors/services.html)

This is the script that I used.

```
$(function () {
    var url = window.location;

    $('ul.active-link a[href="' + url + '"]').parent().addClass('active');


    $('ul.active-link a').filter(function () {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: do you add the complete code?

Comment: Works fine for me. I see the active class being added to the list element for the current tab. What exactly is wrong?

Comment: @ShobhitSrivastava Did you check the link that I post here?

Comment: @CssSY Its working. what is the problem? I'm using chrome. check for browser compatibility.

Comment: Not working for me. Can I see a screenshot?

Comment: @CssSY Which browser you are using?

Comment: Okay this might sound extremely basic, but did you do a hard refresh(Ctrl+Shift+R) after changing your CSS/JS?

Comment: Chrome. Css files are working..

Comment: It's working on firefox! But not working with chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var location = window.location.href;
    $('#nav li a').each(function(){
        if(location.indexOf(this.href)>-1) {
           $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.